# Why is there no option to login as root?

Tags: security, root

Why does Ubuntu not allow the GUI users to login as root at the time of system start up like administrator in Windows?

Why they are restricting us to login only through the terminal?

Comment: Please also be aware of 'gksu' which allows you to run graphical apps as root. I.e. "gksu nautlius"

Comment: Some distros do allow you to login to X as root.  CentOS6.2 is one of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it bad to log in as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-log-in-as-root)

Answer (score 43):

Because it is not recommended doing so unless you know **exactly** what you are doing. Root is a superuser, meaning it can do anything and everything - it is only meant for administrative tasks. Day-for-day tasks can bear a security risk that WILL be exploited if EVERYONE (or a large proportion of users) used root. Think Windows - 99% of malware and virus problems are from people using admin accounts for everyday tasks.

Let's look at an example:

What if someone breaks into your system and tells it to erase your disks? If you are running as a normal user, the only files you would (should) be able to remove are those that **belong** to you, and not anyone else. If, say, you had other people using the computer, their files will not be touched at all, no matter how hard you try. That means you will not be able to change any **system** files, and therefore your system will remain rock-solid and unaffected/uninfected.

If you run as root, however, you can wipe the hard drive entirely, probably do some damage to the hardware itself, and generally render the system unusable. Correction: anyone who can get to run a **single** command as root on your computer (some malicious website or an email attachment) can do that.

Take a look [this nice article](http://everyjoe.com/technology/explain-why-not-log-on-as-root/) that might explain it better than I did.

[Here](http://ihazomgsecurityskillz.blogspot.nl/2010/09/running-as-root.html)'s another one.

You can always use `sudo command` or `gksu command` to run the `command` as the superuser, both of those work with graphical and command-line utilities. `sudo` is usually used for CLI, though, and `gksu` is the graphical password promt that does the same thing.

To an extent, they let you become `root` temporarily - much, **much** better than running as root constantly and risking instability.

Comment: But why Fedora allow this option at start up ?

Comment: Ubuntu is designed to be user-friendly, and I would suspect that by disallowing root, they remove the temptation from normal users (read: Linux newbies) running as root.

Comment: I didn't get you.

Comment: My comment was slightly wrong. Let's say this instead: by disallowing graphical root login, it prevents people from running as root UNLESS THEY KNOW WHAT THEY ARE DOING. That is, in my opinion, it should only be allowed for experienced users who know and understand all the risks.

Comment: Now it is fine enough. but why don't fedora cum RH following the reverse path of graphical root login ?

Comment: Evgeny, perhaps you could make your first sentence a bit more friendly ;-) eventhough I agree with you.

Comment: Renjith, if you have one day a Mac, there is also no login as administrator. Basically a user is an administrator in the same sense as of Ubuntu. This user can launch every administrative tasks, but his password is requested each time it is needed. Windows Vista/7 have the same mechanism now, so you can consider that they are in the process of migrating to this architecture.

Comment: It is meant to be slightly aggressive, just to jerk the readers back into reality and **really** make a point.

Comment: If there is no more questions, I'd like to propose to move this into some kind of wiki article. Also, it'd be easier to discuss this on ubuntu forums, would I be right in saying that? If so, close the question by picking the best answer.

Answer (score 13):

In standard Ubuntu, `root` logins are not allowed, neither from the GDM (graphical) login manager, nor from the text console (i.e., the one you get if press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>).

In order to perform `root` (i.e., administrator) operations you have to use the `sudo` command in a terminal, or any GUI equivalent of it: these will ask you for *your* password and then perform the requested privileged operation (and only that one).

The reason for this behavior is, as others have pointed out, that performing `root` operations is *inherently risky* and the number of operations really requiring `root` privileges is comparatively small: by using this `sudo` approach you are running most of the time with a unprivileged account (i.e., harmless to the system and other users) and just get the `root` powers when it's really needed.

An example might help clarify.  Assume you want to install a new service (daemon) on your machine; this is relatively new and you need to read about it and how to configure it to your needs.  You will end up browsing the web a lot to find information, example configs, etc., maybe have some IRC chat to ask for more info -- none of this requires `root` powers! In the end, you only need privileged access for two operations:

1. install the new program (i.e., `sudo apt-get install ...`), and
2. edit the default configuration

A commonly accepted principle in computer security is *always use the least possible privilege level to perform an operation.* -- this reduces the risk that something bad happens because of bugs in the software or errors from the operator.

The Ubuntu default setup goes in this direction; if you were using a `root` login, instead, you would have ended up surfing the internet, doing IRC (and possibly all the other stuff that one does concurrently) from the `root` account, thus needlessly exposing the system to a threat.

**Update:** For your compiler example, I would proceed this way:

1. Login to the node via SSH *as your regular user*, and from another
   Ubuntu or GNU/Linux node where you have a graphical X11 display
   running.  Be sure to enabled X11 forwarding over SSH:

   ```
   ssh -X myuser@remotemachine.example.org
   ```
2. At the shell/SSH prompt, issue the command:

   ```
   sudo /path/to/the/compiler/install/program
   ```

   This will run the compiler installer with `root` privileges, 
   and access (through SSH forwarding) the graphical display in front
   of you.

Comment: Ok. Suppose , I am using one linux machine (having 10 users connected through putty) . I want to install one software(eg: one compiler,also need to set environmental variables for the same) as root to be available for all users. But the installer works only with GUI mode and no command line installer and it will run only with root login. How can i manage the installation? I have met this situation while installing arm-linux-gcc in my ubuntu but i have successfully  installed the same in my fedora machine(RedHat shrike version)

Comment: @Renjit G: well, this is a good question on its own, why don't you just ask it?

Comment: @Renjit G: I meant to suggest you ask a new question. Asking many specific questions is better than asking one multi-faceted one, because it allows detailed and to-the-point answers. By editing the current question, the replies you have already gotten look like they only answer half of your question...

Comment: Thanks Murri .I will definitely follow like that only from my next posts onwards.

Comment: Given a compiler like that, I think most of us would be curious which compiler it is. For any software distributed through APT sources or standalone .deb files, installation through the command line using "sudo" is sufficient (yes, even for all users). It's also possible to install such files from GUI for all users, without being root. The GUI password prompt you get is the equivalent of "sudo".

Comment: @Renjith G: updated answer with some suggestion how to get the graphical compiler install working.

Answer (score 9):

The reasoning behind the use of sudo in Ubuntu can be [found here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo). If you ever need a quick way to "go root" I use `sudo -s` or `sudo -i`.

Comment: And to clarify, I believe that sudo -s creates a root session as the user, while sudo -i creates a root session as the root user.  The easy way to tell the difference is to issue the command, then do a "echo $HOME" to see what environment is being used.  Or "cd ~" then "pwd" would work too.

Answer (score 6):

Aside from the mountains of warnings with using root, you *can* enable root login by logging in and performing the following from terminal:

```
sudo passwd
```

This will first prompt you for your password then will ask you to change UNIX password. The password you enter will be for the `root` account.

The [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) has a great article on the depths of root and sudo within Ubuntu - caveats and pitfalls.

Answer (score 5):

There are two questions here. One is, why is root login disabled by default in Ubuntu? That's been addressed by several of the posts here.

The second question is, why are graphical root logins particularly disparaged?

All the disadvantages of nongraphical root logins apply to graphical root logins too. But when you log in graphically, you run far more programs, operating in a far more complex way, than when you log in nongraphically. The entire graphical user interface and all the graphical programs needed to use a GUI effectively, would be running as root. A tiny security vulnerability in any of them would enable someone to take complete control over your system.

Logging in as root at all is not recommended in Ubuntu, but there is no consensus in the security community that it is universally a bad practice. Graphical root logins, however, are simply a bad practice, and almost all operating systems have phased them out or strongly recommend against them.

To a lesser degree, having a non-root user (especially one with the ability to perform operations as root with sudo or PolicyKit) in a graphical login presents risks. But they are far more controlled than when everything in the graphical environment must actually be running as root with unlimited capabilities. Still, for situations where security is paramount, it is usually advisable to do away with graphical interfaces altogether, which is why Ubuntu Server doesn't ship with a GUI by default and officially recommends against installing one (though it is supported to do so).

In the Windows world, you can now install Windows Server in a way that [essentially eliminates the graphical user interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_server_core#Server_Core) (technically, some elements remain, but it is very stripped down and you cannot run arbitrary graphical programs). This is based on the same reasoning.

Even if you do decide to enable root logins, please don't log in graphically as root. Enabling root logins may put you at slightly higher security risk; running an entire graphical environment as root puts you at enormously higher risk.

Additionally, with the exception of graphical administration tools that are designed to be run as root with gksu/gksudo/kdesudo, most graphical programs are not intended to be run as root. Because they are not extensively tested in this mode, they may fail or behave erratically (which would be particularly bad, since they're *running as root*).

Finally, even some graphical administration tools, [like `users-admin`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-system-tools/+bug/685215), will fail if run as root, since they expect to be run by normal users and to perform actions as root (without ever actually running as root) using PolicyKit.

Answer (score 4):

Open Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or Dash home > More Apps > Installed (Expand) > Terminal).

TO ACTIVATE THE ROOT ACCOUNT

In a terminal type or paste `sudo passwd root`.
Enter your normal login password (if you are asked for it), then you will be asked to enter the new `root` password and confirm it.

TO ADD A NEW LOGIN PROMPT THAT ALLOWS YOU TO ENTER ROOT AND ITS PASSWORD

In a terminal type or paste. `gksudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`. This opens a graphical text editor window where you can edit the configuration file for the login screen.

Add the line `greeter-show-manual-login=true` to the bottom of the file.

The file should now read as follows:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-show-manual-login=true
```

Save the `lightdm.conf` file and exit from gedit.

Reboot Ubuntu 12.04 and you will see a new “Login” window (replaces the previous "Other" window) which allows for Username and Password input . Enter `root` for the username and then enter the password you assigned to the root account.

I hope this helps others that need/want `root` access.

Answer (score 2):

as for ubuntu 12.04 LTS you can do this using root privilege:

```
echo "greeter-hide-users=true" >> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Then you are asked to type both the username and password to login graphically. I'm assume you have already set the password for root:)

I know there are countless reason that you shouldn't login directly as root, however, there  does exit some rare cases (for example in a test box running in vmware) when you really appreciated the convience of being root.

Answer (score 1):

Because the root user and Administrator (in Windows) are the equivalent of a God to a computer.  That user can adjust anything from file permissions to even erasing the entire file system.  It is quite common for the average home user to run as the Administrator (either under that name or another name set up at first boot).  Because any program executed as that user is system wide, it becomes dangerous.

The lack of control over Administrative privileges allows for virus/malware or even self-destructive issues.  It is because of this that many distros, including Ubuntu, limited the transition to the high power by an extra step (a somewhat cognitive step that helps to insist that "any changes I make here are changes that are grander in scope").

Comment: heh heh. ... "any changes that I make here are grander in scope".

Answer (score 1):

Although you can't login directly as root (for the reasons that others have already explained well), you can run GUI applications as root. For example, *System → Administration → Synaptic Package Manager* is a graphical application that runs as root.

To run an application as root (either a text application or a GUI application), just use one of this commands:

```
sudo name-of-the-application
gksu name-of-the-application
```

They're almost identical. The main difference is that the first asks for your password on the terminal, the second uses a graphical dialog window.

Comment: The difference between `sudo` and `gksu` is more significant than where you enter your password.  `gksu` is preferred for GUI apps and `sudo` for command line see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11825/is-the-difference-between-sudo-and-gksu-the-same-as-the-difference-between-sudo) and [here](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/graphicalsudo)

Answer (score 1):

Root really isn't advised for normal usage but sometimes you have a long list of terminal commands that need root privileges and it's just more convenient to login as root.
  I use `sudo xterm` or `gksu xterm` to open a root terminal
  I think its a little easier to distinguish which term window has root privileges wheen you have the handy "root@" term prompt

Answer (score 0):

Additional note : Ubuntu is not allowing the GUI users to login as root because Ubuntu prevent you to accidentally remove or delete important files with GUI apps (like nautilus).

With only CLI user interface, it can be reduce the risk of our mistake.
But formerly we can't log in with root even in CLI mode because Ubuntu create a random password for root. Root administrative task can only be done by using the user's password with command sudo or gksu.

It's based on Debian rule.

Comment: what gksu command means?

Comment: man gksu : gksu - GTK+ frontend for su and sudo

Comment: Sorry.Again , not clear enough to me

Comment: I mean 'gksu' means GTK+ frontend for su and sudo.

Comment: when we type 'man gksu' in 'terminal', he describes all the functions of 'gksu', including what it means. you can try it. :)

Comment: ok sure. That means the GTK+frontend(gksu) provides the su/sudo GUI root authentication window to the GUI user?

Comment: yes, you're right. try 'gksu nautilus' in the terminal. Nautilus with root privileges will appear.

Comment: I don't know about you, but my most important files are owned by my limited user account and reside in my home directory. They are my documents. System files can be replaced by reinstalling Ubuntu. A document with changes a user has not yet backed up is a much more important file. Furthermore, a novice user is *far* more likely to cause data loss by running commands in the Terminal than by using a graphical program. (For example, see my comment [here](http://www.watchingthenet.com/restore-panels-in-ubuntu-back-to-their-default-settings.html).)

Comment: Also, that root is disabled by default in Ubuntu, and that root login is not officially supported, is not from Debian at all. When you install Debian, you get to choose between having an enabled root account and having a disabled root account and a non-root administrator who can sudo to root.

Comment: Finally, it is **factually incorrect** to say that the root account has a random password in Ubuntu. The account is disabled in `/etc/shadow` with a password entry of `!`; that is not the same as saying the password is random. See [shadow(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/shadow.5.html).

Answer (score 0):

Given that **there are no good reasons to login as root**, I would guess the difference between RH (allow root login) and ubuntu (do everything using sudo/gksu) is a matter of preference.

As for the other part of your question you should be able to run your graphical installation by logging in as a regular user, pressing `ALT-F2` and entering `gksu`. In the resulting dialog just enter the command that launches your installer.

Answer (score 0):

Root is **not** recommended for day to day daily task. As it provides u superuser previledges it can be misused.thus there is no option for root on login.

Answer (score 0):

You should always log on as yourself and then sudo to perform actions as root.  Ubuntu is set up to allow you most all access needed by default.  Minor changes will take care of the rest (like adding your used to other groups).  It is considered poor practice to log in as root.  The industry best practice is the default set up here.

Someone able to log in as root can be a very bad thing from a security perspective.