# why my root password is not working?

Tags: root

I guess as the root password is default user account password (if i am wrong correct me) in terminal when I type su it asks me password when I enter my password it says Authentication failure why is it happening??

Comment: tryn sudo -s or sudo -i

Comment: Similar question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/444246/why-dont-i-have-a-password-for-su-problems-with-sudo/444271#444271

Answer (score 2):

By default Ubuntu does not set up a root password and therefore you don't get the ability to log in as root.  Instead you are given the ability to perform tasks with superuser privileges using sudo.

I've answered a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444246/why-dont-i-have-a-password-for-su-problems-with-sudo/444271#444271) before.

While you *can* create a password for the root account allowing you to log in as root with `su`, this isn't the typical "Ubuntu" way of doing things.

Sudo is an alternative to giving people a root password in order to perform superuser duties.  In a default Ubuntu install the person who installed the OS is given "sudo" permission by default.

Anybody with "sudo" permission may perform something "as a superuser" by pre-pending `sudo` to their command.  For instance, to run `apt-get dist-upgrade` as a superuser, you could use:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

You will see this usage of sudo pretty much anywhere you read a tutorial about Ubuntu on the web.  It's an alternative to doing this.

```
su
apt-get dist-upgrade
exit
```

With sudo, you choose in advance which users have sudo access. There is no need for them to remember a root password, as they use their own password.  If you have multiple users, you can revoke one's superuser access just by removing their sudo permission, without needing to change the root password and notify everyone of a new password.  You can even choose which commands a user is allowed to perform using sudo and which commands are forbidden for that user.  And lastly, if there is a security breach it can in some cases leave a better audit trail showing which user account was compromised.

Sudo makes it easier to perform a single command with superuser privileges.  With `su`, you permanently drop to a superuser shell which must be exited using `exit` or `logout`.  This can lead to people staying in the superuser shell for longer than necessary just because it's more convenient than logging out and in again later.

With sudo, you still have the option of opening a permanent (interactive) superuser shell with the command:

```
sudo su
```

... and this can still be done without any root password, because `sudo` gives superuser privileges to the `su` command.

*And similarly, instead of `su -` for a login shell you can use `sudo su -` or even `sudo -i`.*

However when doing so you just need to be aware that you are acting as a superuser for every command.  It's a good security principle not to stay as a superuser for longer than necessary, just to lessen the possibility of accidentally causing some damage to the system (without it, you can only damage files your user owns).

Just to clarify, you *can*, if you choose, give the root user a password allowing logins as root, if you specifically want to do things this way instead.  I just wanted to let you know about the Ubuntu convention of preferring `sudo` instead and let you know that there is an alternative.