# My root user account is not in the sudoers file

Tags: command-line, sudo

How do i add my root user name to sudeors file in my Ubuntu operating system, because i can not have access as a root user now.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/444246/why-dont-i-have-a-password-for-su-problems-with-sudo