# What is password for root?

Tags: root

I know my administrative and account password. But, whenever I try to change it or do anything like connecting to wifi, connecting to a new internet connection whether it be wired or a mobile network, or anything work, my Ubuntu 12.04 ( Which I have been using since 2012) is showing this message for a few days, I will be highly grateful if someone tells me how to solve this , I deadly need to connect wifi at least. [image: This Pic]

Comment: Click on "Details" to display details, then post what's in there.

Comment: If you haven't set root password set it using  `sudo passwd root`

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/189907/what-is-the-default-root-password?rq=1

Comment: My guess is your administrative account has somehow lost its administrative power, or your system is otherwise similarly misconfigured. In a Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), what's the output of `groups`? And are you able to run a command as root with `sudo`--for example, what happens when you run `sudo echo success`? And can you run a command as root with `pkexec`? Try `pkexec echo success` too. For the PolicyKit authentication dialog to ask you for *root*'s password is extremely strange on Ubuntu. This deserves to be investigated and properly fixed.

Comment: In short, the more relevant question here is probably "why am I being asked for a root password".  If you account has sudo access, you should normally just be asked for your *own* password.