# how can i find out my password for root since i am not a sudo user?

Tags: dell, password, sudo, root

i am asked for the password for root to edit my account settings,upgrade,especially for authentication,but i am not a sudo user.so i don't know how to solve this password asking problem

if i enter any sudo command,it gives the following as result

```
deepak@deepak-Inspiron-3542:~$ sudo aplay -l
[sudo] password for deepak: 
deepak is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
deepak@deepak-Inspiron-3542:~$ sudo -l
[sudo] password for deepak: 
Sorry, user deepak may not run sudo on deepak-Inspiron-3542.
deepak@deepak-Inspiron-3542:~$
```

this are the results when i run sudo commands.in such a situation i don't know how to tackle this password problem.so i need help to find out the password for root.

Comment: If you aren't a sudoer, I guess you either screwed up your root access or you are not supposed to perform administrative tasks on this system.

Comment: It doesn't ask for "PASSWORD FOR ROOT", but rather for "password for deepak". Do you own the machine?

Comment: Ask your admin to fix this ;)

Comment: Add the output of `groups` and `id` commands.

Answer (score -1):

If it's your computer and if you are only one user, the password should be the same as login password. Otherwise it will be predefined password either from another user or Ubuntu

Comment: i entered same password,but it showed it as error

Comment: [setting a root password](http://askubuntu.com/questions/189907/what-is-the-default-root-password) maybe this can help you

Comment: That's the right password: `deepak is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.` -1