# What is the default root login password for ubntu desktop iso

Tags: password, root

I tried installing ubnto 14 on a virtual box. During the install, I was asked for a customer username and password. But am unable to login as root ( using 'su' command ). AM getting an incorrect password error

Kindly help me in getting the right password for root...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the default root password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/189907/what-is-the-default-root-password)

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu does not set the password for root on installation. Instead, run

```
sudo -i
```

and enter the password of the user which is logged in. You are now root. If you want to use su command to become root type

```
passwd root
```

after you have gained root privileges with "sudo -i". After the root password is set you should be able to run "su".