# If I reinstall ubuntu, will i be able to change my root password?

Tags: password

i forgot my old one. can't access GRUB because the piece of Ubuntu i use is the terminal, i don't have any interface.

Comment: By default Ubuntu installs without a 'root' password; though one can be added post-install.  If you install over it (& format) it will re-install & again have the default no root password. Depending on choices made, you could be asked your password (eg. no format, encrypted partitions etc) before it'll re-install without format, but you can overwrite your system clean (assuming the password is not a hdd/sdd or hardware-firmware-level password)

Answer (score 1):

I may be mistaken but I don't think that there is a "Root" password. There is only the user password and whether or not the user can have access to "Root".

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/189907/what-is-the-default-root-password

Comment: It's common for new users who have set automatic login, to forget the password associated with their user.  They often refer to this as the "root" password....

Comment: @CharlesGreen How true. I set up a server for my brother one time. With auto login on. He was trying to do something and said "I don't have a password". Not sure how he missed that file on his desktop with the filename in all caps "this is your password" .