# Why is my trackpad not working in Lubuntu 14.10?

Tags: lubuntu, 14.10, trackpad

Just installed Lubuntu 14.10 on Toshiba Satellite A305-S6872. Cursor is immediately in middle of screen and will not move. Is there something I can do from the terminal that will fix the issue? The other, similar questions on this site seem to be unanswered. Hopefully someone can come forward with some useful info. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer the question. Could you please list what kind of Satellite laptop you have and any solutions you may have tried?

Comment: Also tried sudo apt-get update just in case I was missing something, but my options are pretty limited at this point. Can open terminal, shutdown, and reboot.

Comment: Does an USB mouse work?

Comment: yes, indeed. so now i have greater function. but as to the underlying issue, is it a known ish? Or could it possibly be a driver? Was working fine before upgrade to 14.10

Comment: I mean should I do a reinstall? That seems a bit drastic if there's a pretty simple workaround

Comment: Update. Doing  full reinstall now. Will update with result and hopefully the fix. However, input is still most welcome.

Comment: Please try the solution provided here if it does not yet work after an reinstall: http://askubuntu.com/questions/262287/synaptic-touchpad-on-laptop-not-working

Comment: Reinstall seems to have resolved the issue. But the above comment by Smile4ever looks too be a pretty solid fix as well. Thanks!

Comment: Well, several reboots later after applying both fixes, its still a no go.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I followed the solution ref by @Smile4ever above. The main issue others might run into is creating the file in `/etc/modprobe.d` due to permissions.
In terminal:

```
gksudo nautilus
```

This opens terminal as admin so be careful.

Next:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf
```

In gedit type:
`options psmouse proto=imps`

Save and exit.

In terminal:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

the end, roll credits

Comment: I don't see the need for the first command -- gksudo nautilus might merely open nautilus with root permissions, and it's [just asking for trouble](http://askubuntu.com/questions/423040/what-are-the-risks-of-running-nautilus-as-root#423401). I recommend removing that part of your answer as it's not necessary for the rest of your procedure.