# How to copy files with superuser rights without gksudo nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, gksudo

I'm tired of having to start the `gksudo nautilus` file browser every time I want to copy a file, but don't have the correct privileges for it. How can I grant my account the permanent privileges to copy and delete files in locations like these?

Comment: How often do you have to do this? O.o Where do you copy these files to?

Comment: [Please don't](http://askubuntu.com/questions/423040/what-are-the-risks-of-running-nautilus-as-root)

Answer (score 3):

Run this command:

```
sudo cp /path-from /path-to/
```