# Pasting files as root

Tags: permissions, nautilus, paste

Before asking questions, I'd like to clarify that I will be talking about Ubuntu 16.04.1.

I often find myself trying to paste (or create) files in folders which require that I have superuser privileges to do so, leading to a disabled "New folder/document" or "Paste" option. Is there any way that I can bypass that other than running `sudo nautilus` or `sudo cp`? The truth is I find the pop-up window that Windows provide too nice to part with.

I was able to find similar questions, but none of the answers mentioned anything like what I am looking for (plus most of them are about 3 years old).

I was also able to find [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118822/how-to-launch-application-as-root-from-unity-launcher) (I guess I could use it to launch Files as root), but:

1. There are three .desktop's in my `/usr/share/applications/` (all with the same properties except for the size - the first one being 465 bytes, the second one 647 and the last one 704) so I don't know which one I should edit.
2. I would still not be entirely satisfied as by using the root launcher I could end up accidentally "breaking things".

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/423040/what-are-the-risks-of-running-nautilus-as-root

Answer (score 0):

The Command-Line Way (rather than What-You-See-Is-All-You-Get):

```
echo "something, or cat, or, ..." | sudo tee /etc/init/confuse-a-cat
```

`tee` will let you append to the target file, as well, see `man tee`.