# How to grant root privileges when I generate an OTR key in Pidgin

Tags: 14.04, permissions, pidgin

I recently installed Pidgin on my Ubuntu machine along with OTR plugin. When I tried to generate a key,  I get the following error in my console:

```
>> Could not write private key file
```

I think that maybe the normal user doesn't have the privileges for that action so I switch to root user.

Then when I tried to generate the OTR key, all worked fine.

The problem now is that every time I run `sudo pidgin` in my console, I don't see any windows of the program. and I get the following error in my console:

```
(Pidgin:12241): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/georgegks/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
```

So all in all I have two questions:

1. Why I can't generate an OTR key on a normal user account?
2. Why no window pop ups when I run the pidgin as root?

Comment: You should probably run the famous `sudo chown -R $USER: ~` to get back possibly messed up ownership of all files in your home directory after having used `sudo pidgin`. Otherwise you might encounter problems later...

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found it.

Install `gksu`

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

Then run the program using `gksu` and not `sudo` command

```
gksu pidgin
```

## Explanation:

Based on [Ubuntu Documentation Page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo):

> You should never use normal sudo to start graphical applications as
>   root.   You should use gksudo (kdesudo on Kubuntu) to run such
>   programs. gksudo sets   HOME=~root, and copies .Xauthority to a tmp
>   directory. This prevents files   in your home directory becoming owned
>   by root.   (AFAICT, this is all that's special about the environment
>   of the started     process with gksudo vs. sudo).

So `gksu` is basically a graphical frontend for sudo that allows graphical command to be run without the need to run an X terminal emulator and using su directly

Reference: [This Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11825/is-the-difference-between-sudo-and-gksu-the-same-as-the-difference-between-sudo)