# How do I make Ubuntu not ask me for my password?

Tags: login, password

I'm confident that I do not need a password for my computer. How do I remove passwords for things like when the screensaver activates and installing software?

Comment: It's easy enough to avoid the need to supply a password when you initially log in. But how do you do that on subsequent logins, i.e. when you log in after you've logged out? Or is that simply not possible?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

While this statement is a general attitude that I dont agree with, in the spirit of answering your question, I'll continue without further biased objectification.

There are a few areas of the system that you can utilize to process this request. First being the "Screensaver Password" that you mention. Go to System > Preferences > Screensaver
In there, you need to disable the checkbox titled "ALock screen when screensaver is active"

[image]

On the login screen you can set an auto-login to a user. System > Preferences > Login (this may be system > administration > login.. please verify as I'm not in-front of my Linux PC) you can then set the system to auto-login a given user.

[image]

However please note that after you have logged in, if you have stored passwords in your couchdb it will prompt you to enter your password to unlock the keyring so your wifi can auto connect (as an example)

Regarding your software installation password, there is no way to default this that I'm aware of, as sudo will ask you for a password. This security model is enabled so you have to think about what you're doing before you make system-wide changes such as installing software.

Please see: [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-run-as-root/16179#16179). it will help to explain why the current security model should  be the default.

Comment: +1 for answering a question I'd not be able to answer.

Comment: This is different in Ubuntu 16. Go to "System Settings", then "Brightness & Lock". Either put the Lock switch to "OFF", or uncheck "Require my password when waking from suspend".

Comment: Ubuntu 16, I go to `System --> Users-and-Groups --> password settings`

Comment: This answer is very likely to need to be updated and change with the forward-facing changes Ubuntu desktop is undergoing with the shift to Gnome desktop by default. As this was answered back in 2011 i'm surprised these instructions are still even useful :)

Answer (score 11):

"Nobody will ever compromise my computer." falls under the category of Famous Last Words.  Reconsider.

That said:  for the screensaver, go into the screensaver preferences and uncheck the option to ask for password.  For administrative tasks, `visudo` and change `yourname    ALL=(ALL) ALL` to `yourname    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`.

Answer (score 9):

Simply follow the following command line steps for your PC not prompting for any password.

Edit the file

```
$ sudo visudo
```

Find the line

```
$ %sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Change the line

```
$ %sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Now the line should be look like

```
 # Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
   $ %sudo  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Save and exit(ctrl+x->type 'y'->enter)

Yes you got your way clear...
Although this may help you..
Become the superuser by typing command

```
$ sudo su
```

It will not ask for any password while doing your sudo command stuff.

**More simple way...**

1.Go to gear icon on top right corner.

2.Go to system settings.

3.Go to user accounts,bottom right corner(depends on UI)

4.Click the button **unlock**,it will prompt for password.

5.Enter the password for **particular user**.

6.Slide the bar of Automatic login from **OFF** to **ON**.

7.Here you go..click the **lock** button again.

Thanks..Hope it works.

Answer (score 4):

There's a multitude of reasons why having password protection on sudo actions, or login, but if you really need to not do this you can do it like this:

```
sudo visudo
```

Find the line with your username and change it to the following:

```
$yourname ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

That *should* give you the results you require...

Answer (score 2):

For Lubuntu 17.10:

Click on start > Preferences > Default applications for LXSession > Autostart > Untick the box next to "Screen Locker".

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice alternative during installation. On the page where you are asked for your name and the name of the computer, there is a check-box "log in automatically without asking for a password". This fixes the screensaver problem without compromising root security.