# how do I change permissions?

Tags: 12.10, permissions, password

On my new install of Ubuntu 12.10, I keep having to enter passwords for EVERYTHING! I am the only user on this computer, and I am tired of having to enter all these passwords, can anyone help?

Comment: Does http://askubuntu.com/q/29958/19490 answer you question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computer is set up with at least 2 accounts. If you are a single user you have 2 roles: user and administrator. The last one requires a sudo password every time you do an admin task. That is the way Ubuntu works and is part of the security model Ubuntu follows.

You can circumvent sudo with

```
sudo visudo
```

If you add a line like

```
%Arathorn867 ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/k3b
```

user Arathorn867 can use program k3b without it asking a sudo password.

---

If you want to remove this security model you can alsofollow this guide:

http://my.opera.com/Viperstryker/blog/how-to-disable-sudo-password-prompts-on-ubuntu

But we AskUbuntu all (well at least alot of us) advice AGAINST it. Just get used to this method.

Answer (score 0):

It is all a security issue. If you want root to be available to anyone that might hack into your computer... by all means take away sudo. Think about it a while and then you might want to ask why Windows gets broken into so easily, they have done as you are asking.