# How to disable password after login to 14.04?

Tags: login, password, 14.04

After my update there is a password-request on startup. I want to autologin. It reads something like unlock bunch of keys and is inside a window together with an icon of two keys.

Comment: You want to disable the password or with the password enable autologin?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make Ubuntu not ask me for my password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/29958/how-do-i-make-ubuntu-not-ask-me-for-my-password)

Comment: I want to disable it completely.

Comment: Well, the answers is "you can't".

Comment: Why? I guess it's from Gnome?

Answer (score 5):

See "users accounts" (dash, start typing 'user):

[image]

You need to unlock to make changes (top right).

Comment: Hello. Unfortunately if I press unlock I still can't change it. And it already is set to on.

Comment: Are you an administrator?

Comment: I definitely should. There is no other user (just guest).

Comment: Now there was a box. But it's not this password. There isn't a screen. It's a window which asks me to type in the pwd in order to legitimate the bunch of keys.

Comment: correct that is the unlock thing. provide the password and you can change settings.

Comment: Unfortunately that comes up everytime I start up.