# I can't change audio/volume preferences?

Tags: sound

When I click to sound icon on the panel, I have 3 options:

> "Mute all" is gray and could not be clicked
>
> Slider - I can slide but it DOESNT change anything
>
> Preferences - Shows [this](http://uloziste.eu/show-image.php?id=d02bc129aefaa03dd7a6b1dea2105156)
>
> [image]
>
> (waiting for the response from audio
> device), but it doesn't show anything
> for more than a hour

This is from `aplay -l` :

```
root@fb:~# aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: ALC272 Analog [ALC272 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevices #0: subdevice #0
karta 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: ATI HDMI [ATI HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevices #0: subdevice #0
root@fb:~#
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that `pulseaudio` daemon is not running.

Go to `Startup Applications`

1. Click on <kbd>`Add`</kbd>.
2. Click on <kbd>`Browse`</kbd> and select `/usr/bin/pulseaudio` and click on <kbd>`Add`</kbd>.

Finally `logout` and then `login` the system.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work in root.

Working as root is heavily discouraged. Please use an "administrative" account (an account that can use sudo and equivalents) instead.

Comment: @genesis Sorry, you what?

Comment: @genesis: you don't need a root account to run and administrate Ubuntu. It is strongly discouraged: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-run-as-root

Comment: I DO NOT MIND ABOUT THIS. It's not what I asked

Comment: @genesis It is directly related to your problem.

Comment: but it can be work-arounded

Comment: @genesis Why use workarounds if there is a proper solution to a problem?

Comment: because I like using root rather than just admin account

Comment: @genesis Why? It only causes problems - e.g. some applications will refuse to run (like VLC)

Comment: @nick: yes, that's bad, I have to switch it in case I want to run VLC ...