# A driver depends on OpenGL, what package provides it?

Tags: 11.04, 10.04, dependencies, opengl

My device software dependencies are: dkms opengl gcc glibc kernel-headers. But when i install opengl it fail. What i have to use in 10.04 and 11.04 (i have both installed side by side for learning)

**Follow up:**

Step 1: dkms/gcc/glibc

```
# apt-get install dkms
# apt-get install build-essential
```

Step 2: kernel-headers

```
# apt-cache search linux-headers-$(uname -r)
>linux-headers-2.6.32-33-generic - Linux kernel headers for version 2.6.32 on x86/x86_64
# apt-get install linux-headers-2.6.32-33-generic
```

Step 3: OpenGL

```
# apt-get install opengl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package opengl
--- see answer

--- verify
# glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 7.7.1
```

Done.

Comment: Since you're learning, I recommend you *not* to be root all the time. See http://askubuntu.com/q/16178/6969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mesa's OpenGL libraries is provided by [libgl1-mesa-glx](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libgl1-mesa-glx)[image: Install libgl1-mesa-glx]. The development headers can be found in the [libgl1-mesa-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libgl1-mesa-dev)[image: Install libgl1-mesa-dev] package.