# Ubuntu laging and can I turn off root password?

Tags: password, samsung

Hello I have problem with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, it's always give me a lag and I don't know what to do.

My [laptop](http://www.samsung.com/ae/consumer/computers-peripherals/notebook/high-performance/NP300V5A-S0AAE) I think is fast, so how can you help me ?

And one other problem, how to remove password for admin, because system always request the password, for everything ??

Comment: Could you state when the computer lags and what you are doing at the time ?

Comment: just surfing in the internet and everything always lag, browser gets to the dark color and everything stops

Comment: You can try "sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop" to refresh the desktop in a terminal and "sudo apt-get update" to update software sources and then run update manager to make sure you have the latest packages

Comment: Also what type of graphics do you have ? Check system settings / additional drivers in case you need drivers

Comment: i made updates and reinstalled desktop, maybe it will help. thanks

Comment: No proprietary drivers are in use on this system - i get this message in setttings/additional drivers

Comment: One last suggestion, try another browser see if the problem persists I can recommend Google chrome or oprah  both can be installed from there respective home pages and uninstalled with software center good luck

Answer (score 0):

You should not remove the admin password as this will allow your system to be hacked an insecure but you can log in as root  [READ THIS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122922/how-do-i-log-into-gnome-as-a-root)

This will allow you to by pass the password and you can find your old home folder at /home/username

This is not recommended my best advice to you is use a short password and dont be lazy..:)