# Sound devices refuse to work on root GUI login (11.10)

Tags: 11.10, sound, hardware

The GUI for configuration shows an absence of any sound devices. Sound works fine for other users.

How do I fix this?

Comment: perhaps you can explain further in  your question why you need to use a root GUI login and also need sound. Logging in as a standard user probably will be better from a security point-of-view.

Comment: Explain? I understand the risks and I am careful not to lose data or kill a production machine. Pleeeaaase? :D

Comment: It's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/549074) -- sorry.

Answer (score 5):

It's **broken on purpose** so you don't screw stuff up.

The proper way to do stuff with root is to use `sudo` and `gksu`.

Logging in with the root account is a really bad idea, and it's really easy to screw stuff up to the point where you can't fix it. As such, the margin for error is... small at best.

Related: [Why is it bad to login as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-run-as-root)