# How do I remove google chrome which is not starting anymore?

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, uninstall

I have tried to make google chrome run as root using [this](http://bikramkawan.com.np/run-google-chrome-as-root-on-any-ubuntu-100-works-for-all-linux/) tutorial but now simply Google Chrome won't start.

If I try from terminal with `google-chrome` I get:

```
root@ubuntu:~# google-chrome 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

If I try to uninstall from the software center, it simply hangs when I click on installed software. I tried `apt-get purge` but with no success. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run the following command as root: `apt-get purge google-chrome-stable`.

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti Why are you running a browser as root? Please read this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-run-as-root

Comment: Because i'm lazy and i don't want to type sudo. It's a VM i have to install to develop on node + redis because doing that on windows it's a real pain, i don't see any security issue in doing this. If someone can access my windows user / passowrd i would have problems anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to `/usr/bin`, edit `google-chrome`. I did it with Kate.

At the end of `exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@"`, add `--user-data-dir`, so it looks like this: `exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@" --user-data-dir`.

Answer (score 0):

Kill chrome in system monitor and then try removing it.

Comment: I'm new to ubuntu, what is system monitor?

Comment: Equivalent of Windows Task Manager.

Comment: @ArupRoyChowdhury This answer would be improved if you were to add instructions for opening the System Monitor and/or a screenshot showing how. (I would edit this in myself, but I am currently on a Lubuntu system, which uses a different utility, launched differently.)

Answer (score 0):

You can kill Chrome from the System Monitor: Launch it from the Unity ta sk bar (it's just called "System Monitor") or launch it from the terminal with `gnome-system-monitor` -- you'll see all running processes under the "Processes" tab. You might have a few "Chrome" processes running (I had four just now) -- select the processes called chrome and use the "End Process" button to kill them.