# Ubuntu "1 time password on login" solution

Tags: security, password, sudo, users, administrator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is it bad to run as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-run-as-root)

I recently fully switched from Windows into Ubuntu. And of course I loved Ubuntu. But the most annoying thing is, system requires password every single time you do something. Is there any way to configure system so that, to enter the password only on logon screen. I mean 1 time you enter password and logon. Then system must know that you're his boss, and no need to ask every time for password. I don't want to change any system file for this purpose, but if there is any legal way to do it, I'd be very happy.

Thanks in advance for wasting your time and trying to help

Comment: To better see if your system setup may have an issue please give us an example of *"something"* where you are being asked for your password. In a normal setting you definitely do not need your password *"everytime you do something"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, this is avoided for security. It may be annoying, but it's better than a rogue program messing up your computer. The functionality you're describing is running as the root user, which is generally avoided like the plague (again, for security). There are some times when it's necessary, but you mostly will just have to stick with typing in your password each time. If you have a fingerprint reader, you can use that to authenticate quicker.