# Can I write a python script that will automatically load a terminal as sudo?

Tags: command-line, python, scripts, sudo

I use `sudo` a lot and I am constantly having to restart my terminal (development of programs that froze usually) and it's a pain in the butt to constantly put in the `sudo` command and then my password. Is there a way I could through Python (or a script file) get an already sudo terminal?

I wasn't sure if I should post it on Stack Overflow (because of the coding side) or here (because of sudo/terminal stuff).

Comment: try "sudo su" then you're done typing sudo for a while; or if you absolutely have to, then run your python scripts from root. You know the dangers...  I hope

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I know the dangers and I know about `sudo su`/`sudo -i` but like I said in the question, I am constantly restarting the terminal window to apply changes/kill unresponsive programs.

Comment: have you tried ctrl + c when when something is unresponsive, http://superuser.com/questions/243460/what-to-do-when-ctrl-c-cant-kill-a-process

Comment: Just an FYI, no need to edit your title to say "Closed".  When you choose an answer, it changes color accordingly on the main page.  Which is why I rolled back the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-run-as-root), because running ANYTHING as root within a script or other piece of software that COULD be run without the administrator's knowledge is a very very dangerous and bad thing.

As well, running your system in a root terminal just to run a script is also equally dangerous.

(whether you know the security implications or not, question poster, others probably won't, hence this answer)