# Changed root password on my server, now can't login anymore

Tags: server, login, password, sudo, root

I decided to change the root password that came preset on a fresh DigitalOcean server (ubuntu 12.04).

I used the first answer to this post: [How to change root password in ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294946/how-to-change-root-password-in-ubuntu)

which is:

```
sudo -i
passwd
```

(set my new password on prompt)

```
sudo passwd -dl root
```

Now I can't login as root on tty1 on my server, nor can I access my server on Filezilla, etc...

What did I do wrong, and more importantly **how can I recover my root login?**

*Thank you for your help.*

Comment: that last command disabled root

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command

```
 sudo passwd -dl root
```

is for disabling root and removing root password. As explained in `man passwd`:

> -d --delete
>
> Delete a user's password (make it empty). This is a quick way to disable a password for an account. It will set the named account passwordless.
>
> -l --lock
>
> Lock the password of the named account. This option disables a
>   password by changing it to a value which matches no possible encrypted value (it adds a ´!´ at the beginning of the password).

So you just need to set `root` password again.

So, first execute in a terminal

```
sudo passwd root
```

or

```
sudo -i
passwd
```

you will be prompted for a new Unix password. Write it twice (second time for confirmation).

Then execute

```
sudo passwd -u root
```

to unlock the account. This should return

```
passwd: password expiry information changed
```

Now you will be able to access root. But it is not a good idea as you can see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-login-as-root).

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that I don't know how to access the shell prompt again. I am currently stuck on the tty1 login prompt that I access either with their html console (http://bit.ly/1dqtgtz) or via ssh.

Comment: it appears I was connecting to my server this way `ssh mydomain.com@my.server.ip` instead of `ssh root@my.server.ip`. The later allows me directly in shell prompt (if ssh keys are properly set up).