# How do I access the recovery menu

Tags: password-recovery, recovery-mode

I want to change my root password but I am not able to access the recovery menu. I followed the steps given [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword). I choose the advanced option from the grub menu and then the recovery mode, but after that ubuntu loads the GUI mode with a guest session. How do I access the recovery menu so I can change my root password ?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the recovery menu to change the root password.

By default, no root password is set in Ubuntu, and you use `sudo` only to get root permissions. It you really want to set a root password, see

[How to change root password in ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294946/how-to-change-root-password-in-ubuntu)

and for background, see here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

Comment: I wrote the question wrong. I just wanted access to sudo command to remove guest login in ubuntu but i had forgotten my password.

Comment: You can edit your question (there is a link "edit" below)!