# root password on meizu mx4 ubuntu edition

Tags: ubuntu-touch, password, root, meizu-mx4

I just got this brand new phone from Meizu, and immediately after unboxing it, tried to open a terminal, and failed to go to root!
Is there any default root password?

I sucessfully changed the "phablet" password, but changing root password does not work.(Authentication Token error when trying `sudo passwd root`)

Any ideas?
Fab

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change root password in ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/294946/how-to-change-root-password-in-ubuntu?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root user is not enabled but you can become root without setting a password for it.
Just type

```
sudo su
```

in the terminal and give it the password of the phablet user when it asks for one.

//EDIT:

I've tested this with developer mode enabled, where the phablet user's pass is the one used for the lockscreen, though in theory the command above should work even if you've changed the password manually from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

from the box I don't think there should be a password. Otherwise it is whatever you set as a screen unlock code or phrase.

Good luck!