# Why I can't change my ubuntu root password?

Tags: permissions, password, users, user-profile, passwd

I've been using Ubuntu 15.04 for a while with my password, so far so good (I'm the only user and root). But I wanted to change my password and tried to do that throuth terminal with`sudo passwd`. It asks me for my new password and than tell me the pw was successfully updated. The point is, my password doesn't change, it is the same old one. The new one doesn't work, it looks as if I've done nothing. What is that and how do I fix?

Grateful.

Comment: Kindly check this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/294946/how-to-change-root-password-in-ubuntu

Comment: You need to specify a user.  sudo passwd Lucas

Comment: the password that you use with `sudo` is the one for your account. to change that use `passwd` without `sudo`.

Comment: You are **not** *"the only user and root"* - root is **always** a separate user. You may be the only user and a *member of the  group `sudo`*.

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands:

```
sudo passwd root
```

[enter your user's password]
[enter the password you want]
[enter the same password]

And you're done.