# How to enable root login again after changing password?

Tags: permissions, ssh, login, sudo, password

I had enabled root login before and tried to change its password using this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294946/how-to-change-root-password-in-ubuntu). But after successfully changing the password and locking it via `sudo passwd -dl root`. I cannot login back to SSH, it says **Access is denied**.

I have two users on my machine. root and admin, admin does not have su permission. When I try to use `sudo` on admin user, it says that admin is not in the sudoers file. That is why i need my su user back.

Comment: What account were you using when you executed `sudo passwd -dl root`?

Comment: i was logged in as root. @techraf

Comment: You don't need to add `sudo` when you are logged in as root. Now for the problem: you have locked yourself out of the machine and you won't be able to do anything without a physical access to the disk. Do you have one?

Comment: @techraf i dont have access to the physical machine. how screwed am i?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)