# How do I change my root password in Ubuntu?

Tags: password

I recently posted here regarding a problem I was having with installing VLC media player on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I just read a reply to that message which said if I did not have the root password, I cannot install anything on Ubuntu. I understand that, but I am wondering if it is possible to recover or reset the root password and, if so, how do I do it?

Thank you.

Jeff (jeff5613)

Comment: You don't need a root password in Ubuntu; as everything that can be done by the root user, can be done by a normal user who has `sudo` rights; which is setup at install time.  The `root` user has an invalid password at install time, thus disabling the account (intentionally as it's safer; and not needed).

Comment: you can change it with a simple `sudo passwd`  (ie. `sudo` to elevate your privileges, so the password you're changing is the 'root' account), but you open up your box for more *potential* hacks by doing so; and gain in effect *nothing*.   Just as a learning example... enter `whoami` at terminal when you're you; then try `sudo whoami`.... that's how Ubuntu by default intends users to access root... with the `sudo`   (there is a lot more detail about environments involved... so this is an oversimplification, but it'll show I hope that a root password isn't required)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change root password in ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294946/how-to-change-root-password-in-ubuntu)