# The ADT tools bar does not work?

Tags: android

I download the ADT ball from the Internet and unpack it on Ubuntu 13.10.but the menu bar doesn't work,it cannot show any content when I click it.

Answer (score -1):

Try to run eclipse as sudo.

In my case I tried with:

```
    sudo /home/iocio/Desktop/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/eclipse/eclipse
```

and the problem is solve it.

Edit: Why do you put me -1 point?? Thank you guy.

Comment: Running user applications as root is highly unrecommended. Your command does exactly that. http://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-run-as-root