# Root permissions or logon

Tags: command-line, permissions, root

I know this sounds naive but, why can't I log on as root or give my ID root permissions?
Why do I have to use Terminal?

I mounted a drive and now want to give permissions to other PC on my network to access the drive.

Comment: Also see: http://askubuntu.com/q/16178/158442

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to give others access to the drive, you can use the chmod command along with the -R parameter to invoke the command recursively. Here's an example:

```
sudo chmod -R 666 /media/username/drivename
```

To change ownership, you can use the chown command:

```
sudo chown username:username /media/username/drivename
```

Change "username" to your username and "drivename" to the actual label of the device in your filesystem.

See: [file permissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions).

Answer (score 1):

**By default, the Root account password is locked in Ubuntu**. This means that you cannot login as Root directly or use the `su` command to become the Root user. However, since the Root account physically exists it is still possible to run programs with root-level privileges. This is where `sudo` comes in - it allows authorized users (normally "Administrative" users) to run certain programs as Root without having to know the root password.

*Scraped from [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)*