# how do I establish a root password?

Tags: permissions

During installation for the first time I was not ask for a root password is there a default password? Or is there some way to establish that password?

Comment: You may want to review [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-login-as-root) - there is little or no reason to use the root account in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

At time of installation it asked to create one user and that user is in sudo group. so whenever you run any command with `sudo` it will ask that user password not root. so no need of root password , but if you want to set password then you can 
set password using command:

```
 sudo passwd
```

or

```
sudo passwd root
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard Ubuntu since at least 14.04 has not used the root account in favor of doing everything with `sudo`.  Unless you've used older versions or other distros where root account is the standard way of doing privileged tasks, it's probably better to continue the Ubuntu way: if you find a command that needs root privilege, use `sudo` with your user password (assuming you have a user account that's in the `sudoers` list).

Comment: No, if you set root's password you can use it (unless you're unable to `su` or use other tools to become root due to PAM's or other authentication daemons' policies). `su` by default allows root login, the problem is the default invalid password, which is bypassed by setting a root password.

Comment: @kos -- fixed it.