# How to change root password back to DEFAULT

Tags: root

I already set-up my root password in Ubuntu. But for some reasons now I need to set it back to default as when Ubuntu is freshly installed. I no more need my set root password. How can I set it back to default? I know my root password. When I supply with empty password to set it back to default it says "Cannot be empty"

[image: what I was trying to do..]

Comment: @Takkat, I agree. Marked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To lock the root account, making it unable to login with a password, use this command:

```
sudo passwd -l root
```

It will retain whatever password you have set, but it will be unusable for all purposes.

**EDIT:** This will be useful for any account, besides `root`.

To unlock the password for the account you previously locked, use this:

```
sudo passwd -u root
```

BTW: as was commented, you shouldn't use the `root` account, unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: if i want to enable it again what should i do?

Comment: @Vi_Hari: you don't: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-login-as-root

Comment: thanks, but when running some localhosts for some project purposes it asks for password often. will the change affect only after restart?

Comment: Nope. Locking an account (any account, FTM) is a permanent action, until undone with the command above.