# root login - user@user:/home$ sudo -i root@r00t:~# Voila, I am root and I don't have root password, right?

Tags: permissions, login, sudo, password, root

I'm wondering about the root account being disabled in Ubuntu and whether it makesany difference to security. If someone hacks into your PC they can type:

```
user@user:/home$ sudo -i
root@r00t:~# Voila, i am root and I don't have root password, right?
```

That's an example from my PC , up , so why exactly disable it? For many years I had no doubt about disabled root but now I have this in my mind more and more...

If anyone already hacked into your account/PC via IP or however, what's the difference if root is disabled/enabled if they just have to type `sudo -i` to get root?

Here's a quote from a post here:

> In Linux there is a special account called root. By default it is
>   locked in Ubuntu but you can enable the root account.
>
> This is normally not a good idea however and you should consider very
>   carefully before enabling the root login.
>
> There are several good reasons not to log in as root but to use `sudo`
>   instead including
>
> - Users don't have to remember an extra password (i.e. the root password), which they are likely to forget (or write down so anyone
>     can crack into their account easily).
> - It avoids the "I can do anything" interactive login by default (e.g. the tendency by users to login as an "Administrator" user in
>     Microsoft Windows systems), you will be prompted for a password before
>     major changes can happen, which should make you think about the
>     consequences of what you are doing.
> - `sudo` adds a log entry of the command(s) run (in `/var/log/auth.log`). If you mess up, you can always go back and see
>     what commands were run. It is also nice for auditing.
> - Every cracker trying to brute-force their way into your box will know it has an account named Root and will try that first. What they
>     don't know is what the usernames of your other users are. Since the
>     Root account password is locked, this attack becomes essentially
>     meaningless, since there is no password to crack or guess in the first
>     place.
> - Allows easy transfer for admin rights, in a short term or long term period, by adding and removing users from groups, while not
>     compromising the Root account. sudo can be setup with a much more
>     fine-grained security policy.
>
> This is discussed in more detail in the RootSudo Comunity
>   Documentation
>
> If you have a number of commands which would normally require sudo you
>   can type `sudo -i` before the first command then exit after the last to
>   avoid repeatedly typing sudo. To run a GUI application with root
>   priviledges press ALT+F2 and enter gksu or gksudo followed by the name
>   of your program (unless you are using the KDE desktop in which case
>   the command is kdesu)
>
> For example gksu nautilus runs the file manager with root privileges.
>
> As you can see it is almost never necessary to enable the root login. 
>   That said to enable the root login all that is required is to set a
>   root password
>
> ```
>  sudo passwd root
> ```
>
> and set a password. You will then be able to login as root but for all
>   the reasons I have given above and more I would not recommend you do
>   it.

Comment: what is your question actually? `sudo -i` won't give you root shell unless you type your password (if you're in `sudo` group). That is the settings in Ubuntu.

Comment: Disabling root login is to stop reckless users logging in as root, not to stop malicious activity by others.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-login-as-root

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, the example from your PC is a fake example because the hostname doesn't change when you do `sudo -i`, obviously. Here is a real example:

```
zanna@monster:~$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for zanna:
root@monster:~#
```

(I entered my own user password). Now since I don't actually need this root shell to do anything the first thing I'm going to do is `exit` it.

The main point of disabling root login is to prevent reckless behaviour by users. There's no reason to use root privileges unless you really need to: logging in as root all the time reduces the security of the system to that of a virus- and malware-prone Windows system.

If someone with malicious intent manages to get the password of a user with `sudo` privilege, then you're in just as much trouble as you would be if they had the root password. Ubuntu's design decision in disabling root login makes no difference to that.

Comment: This has inspired me to come up with a creative hostname for my own computer.