# PATH variable issue

Tags: command-line, paths

l have trouble with my PATH variable:

each time l run command like pip, bash, mkdir ..

for instance

```
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
bash: command not found
```

other example :

```
dpkg: warning: 'sh' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: warning: 'rm' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: warning: 'tar' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 5 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

does this command solves the problem  ?

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

each time l need to run this command  , how to solve that ?

This command:

```
/bin/grep PATH ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_login /etc/profile /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/environment
```

returns:

```
/root/.bashrc:export PATH="/root/anaconda3/bin"
/bin/grep: /root/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
/bin/grep: /root/.bash_login: No such file or directory
/etc/environment:PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

Comment: Are you sure its not permission issue? What is the result of `ls -l /bin/bash`?

Comment: @RomeoNinov that's irrelevant. Vincent, please [edit] your question and post the output of this command: `/bin/grep PATH ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_login /etc/profile /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/environment`. You have changed your PATH and that will have happened in one of those files.

Comment: @terdon, please see my update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `/root/.bashrc`, specifically this line:

```
export PATH="/root/anaconda3/bin"
```

First of all, what in the world are you doing adding anaconda to root's PATH? You [really don't want](https://askubuntu.com/q/16178/85695) to be using root as your main user! Anyway, that line doesn't *add* `/root/anaconda3/bin` to root's PATH, it *replaces* the PATH with `/root/anaconda3/bin` and nothing else. So the only command that root can run are the ones in `/root/anaconda/bin`. What you wanted to do, presumably, was add it. So, change the line above to:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/root/anaconda3/bin"
```

Since your PATH is currently messed up, you will need to use the full paths to the relevant commands. For example, to open the file using `nano`:

```
/bin/nano /root/.bashrc
```

Or, if you are not actually logged in as root (as you shouldn't be):

```
/usr/bin/sudo /bin/nano /root/.bashrc
```

Then correct the line, open a new terminal (or log out and log back in) and everything should work again.

Comment: Ok. l did that , but why after executing which anaconda3
 and don't get anything ?

Comment: @vincent as what user?

Comment: root@vincent-OMEN-by-HP-Laptop:/home/vincent/

Comment: @vincent this is going to be hard to figure out in comments (I need to see the output a few commands). Join me in [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57743/room-for-vincent-and-terdon) if you like and we can sort it out.