# Ubuntu 18.10 Enable Remote Desktop for root

Tags: root, remote-desktop, xrdp

I have enabled `root` login on Ubuntu 18.10 with gnome desktop, works fine. I also have installed `xrdp`, and it works fine for normal users but not `root`. I am facing 3 issues:

1. I want to enable remote login for `root`. When I try to login, I get this message below

[image: this error message]

2. For users other than `root`, in xrdp session, I don't see complete gnome desktop as shown in the screenshot below. The sidebar is missing, and there is no Terminal in right click menu. How to fix this?

[image: as shown in this screenshot]

3. How to enable multi-user remote login? I want multiple users to be able to remote login at the same time.

The most important issue to fix is to enable `root` login via `xrdp`. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I am sorry if I sound harsh, but I think what you are trying to do is a terrible idea.
See https://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-log-in-as-root
You be able to do what you want that requires privileged access by using sudo.

Comment: It's not only the desktop that is different, you also can't access some privileged functions. E.g. I'm unable to add a new printer over XRDP even when I'm logged in as a sudoer user.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a password for root if you have not done so:

```
sudo passwd
```

Then you can use username `root` and `password` to log in.

Answer (score 0):

just an idea but worth trying...

**Issue 1 - Allow root Login**

I think that by default xrdp does not allow root to perform remote desktop connection.... you should have a look at the following file  /etc/xrdp/sesman.ini and check if there is any **AllowRootLogin** option.  Set the value to **1,true or yes** to **enable root login** on terminal server

**Issue 2 - XRDP UBUNTU DESKTOP Theme Issue**

For your desktop issue for normal users; this is a know issue. Please have a look at this post (http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12155) which will explain why the behavior occurs and how you can fix it... When performing an xrdp connection, you basically starting with a default gnome desktop experience, you have to execute some commands in order to configure your desktop and have a similar look n feel in xrdp.

Note also that a script that automate the installation process for xrdp exists and can be found here (http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12761).  This script is valid for Ubuntu 18.xx systems. Please always check for latest script version

Hope this help 
Till next time