# How do I login as root?

Tags: sudo, root

I want to login as root, but when I enter

```
sudo -s
```

and enter password, this message is shown: "you are not in sudoers file", and when I enter

```
su
```

and enter password, this is shown: "authentication failure".

My os has one account only. about past1 hours ago I log on as root and do some commands , when I logout , I can't login another time!

Comment: We'd need to know what commands you ran when you were root. You might need to reset your password: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrativeroot-password

Comment: Do you want to change user in terminal as you used su command?
if you want to then you need to have the root password

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The `su` command requires you to put in root password.  Root user on Ubuntu in general is locked so no user can login as `root` thus `su` is not likely to work.

For `sudo -s` to work you will have to be part of the `admin` group on an Ubuntu machine, which apparently you are not.

If you are the only user on the system that is concerning and may be quite involved to fix.  If not I would suggest you talk to the System Administrator or owner of the system to see if you even can get `root` privileges.

Comment: and if it is your machine, and you've somehow lost root privileges, you'll have to fix it by booting into recovery mode.

Comment: My os has one account only. about  past1 hours ago I log on as root and do some commands , when I logout , I can't login another time!

Comment: What commands did you do?

Comment: I don't know exactly. that was some simple commands such as changing umask

Comment: and some shell programming, add group

Comment: Is any way to restore?

Comment: Did you by chance used `usermod`, `groupmod`, `groupdel`, `visudo`, `userdel`, or changed permissions on anything in /etc?

Comment: yes .I use usermod -g ....

Comment: Rule 1: Unless you know what you're doing stay out of SuperUser mode.  In the mean time take a look at: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrativeroot-password

Comment: not any way for me?

Comment: No.  you need to boot into `rescue` mode and then add yourself back to admin group.  Personally I would suggest you get someone who is an expert to help you because if you are not careful you might wind up with a full system reinstall.

Comment: This link explains how to fix sudo: http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/fixsudo

Answer (score 75):

Be aware that the root account is not active by default.

You will need to do:

```
sudo passwd root
```

Then go ahead to set password.
Use the root user using

```
su root
```

Comment: 1. It won't work, if user isn't in `admin` group. 2. Please, **[don't enable login via root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-log-in-as-root).**

Answer (score 27):

The https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo suggests:

> If you really need a persistent Root login, the best alternative is to
>   simulate a Root login shell using the following command...
>
> ```
> sudo -i
> ```

Comment: doesn't work . My os has only one account

Answer (score 7):

First of all you need to have admin privileges. If you don't have admin privileges then while booting press and hold the <kbd>shift</kbd> key. You will enter the GRUB menu. Here select recovery mode. When you see the list of options like `dpkg` etc, choose to start a root shell and type:

```
adduser username sudo
```

(where `username` is your username :-) )

this will add you to the sudoers group! Then type `exit` and boot normally. when you enter your account, type:

```
sudo passwd root
```

Then enter your password and type the new root password

After that you can type `su` and enter the 'root' password.

If you don't want to change the root password then you can use:

```
sudo -i
```

to start a root shell, using your own password.

Comment: Tell me if you want to activate the root account to log in the root account :)

Comment: Just a question, does the recovery mode, you mentioned above, will affect any pre-installed program in the Ubuntu?