# Difference between ~/folder and /home/username/folder when creating a path in /etc/environment

Tags: environment-variables

I had an executable script on my ubuntu located on `~/project/` directory and I tried to add that path to `/etc/environment` . So , I edit the path to this `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:~/project/"` . Then , I logout and login back , open the terminal as `su` and run the command to execute my script on that folder but the result is `command not found`.

Then, I change the path in `/etc/environment` to  `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/r0xx4nne/project/"` and voila it works.Now i can run the executable script inside `~/project/` without fail under `su` command.

My question is , what's the difference between **~/project** and **/home/r0xx4nne/project** when it comes in case of creating a path in **/etc/environment** ?

Why it happened to be like this? I am a newbie and I just want to know more . Thanks for any reply .

Comment: I edited the question a few minutes ago, but it did not change the main objective of the question.Just deleted the `sudo bash` because it is not necessary to put that here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the shell, `~/project/` is expanded to `/home/yourusername/project` in most circumstances. This is called [tilde expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html#Tilde-Expansion).

If you put

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:~/project/
```

(note, without the quotes) in `~/.profile`. Your PATH will be set correctly, because `~/.profile` is interpreted by a shell when you log in. `/etc/environment` (and it's user-specific `~/.pam_environment`) is not interpreted by a shell. It is read by the [pam_env](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/pam_env.8.html) module during login, but it only accepts `NAME=VALUE` pairs and no expansions (like `$var` or `~/` or `$(command)` etc.) will be done on the `VALUE`.

Comment: i think this explain everything.. thanks to you,because all i wanted to know is about the expansions you are talking about and the reason why we can't use tilde on /etc/environment . Thumbs up! :D

Answer (score 1):

When you login as su, `~` is `/root`, not `/home/<yourusername>`.
Otherwise, both are the same.

NB: The tilde is expanded by the shell (and not `ls`) before actually executing the command. For example, if you run `sudo ls ~`, the command that will be executed is `ls /home/<yourusername>` and not `ls /root`. To prevent the shell from expanding the tilde as non-root user, you could:

- [first login as root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91598/how-do-i-login-as-root), then execute the command in the root shell *or*
- pass the command as argument to a shell, and make the shell run as root:

  ```
  sudo bash -c "ls ~"
  ```

Comment: I don't think that's true.  If I do `sudo ls ~/Desktop`, for example, I see **my** desktop, not root's.

Comment: i did like @Thanh said , i login as `su` and do `ls ~/Desktop` and nothing listed in the terminal. But, it won't work for sudo like @Marty said,because it shows my file on desktop . Thanks to both of you.. now I can see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

The tilde stands for the current user's home directory.  It may be yours, or it may be another, depending on when it's used.  If you are not yet logged in, it won't work.

A related problem is that /etc is not your directory, and is not the place to add your personal paths.  If there were another user, why would he have a path to your home directory?

The correct place to modify the path depends on who needs that path:

One user only (you) -- `$HOME/.profile`, where $HOME is /home/username

All users except root -- `/etc/profile`

root -- `/root/.profile`

So, to summarize, your path should be set in `/home/r0xx4nne/.profile`.

Comment: `~/.bash_profile` is not read during graphical login.

Comment: @geirha:   I guess I usually use bash for checking or setting the path, so I once spent time trying to get that working correctly for all types of shells.  But I used to run X from a shell, so I suppose it was different.  So, what about .profile?  I actually see that this is where I set my path.  If that's a better place, I can edit my answer.  But /etc doesn't seem to be the right place in this case, does it?

Comment: Yes, an sh script is run when you log in. It specifically sources `~/.profile` before running the gnome-session (or whichever session you chose), so any environment variables set in `~/.profile` will stick.

Comment: @geirha - Thanks for the heads-up; I edited my answer, and updated my notes about where to change the path.  Somehow, I had researched it a ways back, solved my problem, and made notes, but I guess either something changed or my situation was simply not all-inclusive.