# Ubuntu 12.04 - After release-upgrade from 11.10 - no more root login?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, login, login-screen, root

Question: I did do-release-upgrade on Ubuntu 11.10.

Now, I have Ubuntu 12.04, and I can login as a normal user, but not as root.
On 11.10, I could login as root without problem.

I checked on the console, where root login works fine, and I did sudo passwd to reset the root password just in case, and I can still login on the console, but not on gnome...

Why ? Where's the problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/91598/how-do-i-login-as-root

Comment: I think there's a LightDM policy not to allow UIDs < 500 to login. Search AU with those keywords or google. @fossfreedom probably a dupe, but not the one you linked IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, never mind

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "greeter-show-manual-login=true" >> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf'
```

**is not enough**. Afterwards, you need to switch from gdm to lightdm

```
dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

and use lightdm, then reboot and use the new login option
With gdm, it will still not work...