# How to login in terminal as root anytime when I open terminal?

Tags: command-line, root

I don't want to type sudo and my password everytime.I think it is really annoying.Is there any command or option which will consider you root user when you open terminal,everytime When you open terminal.

Comment: Please, please, _please_ do not do this. It is a horrible idea.

Comment: If you do this, anyone who presses <ctl><alt><T> is root. Any script that opens a terminal is root. Any silly command you type will be executed. You might as well run XP unpatched.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as a duplicate of one that shows you a more reasonable approach to not typing a password. That, at least, won't leave your system quite so unprotected. It is still a horribly silly thing to do but better than what you're asking for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sudo a command in a script without being asked for a password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/155791/how-do-i-sudo-a-command-in-a-script-without-being-asked-for-a-password)

Comment: @terdon: Will you explain what is horrible about it in a personal computer. Is there a threat from a hacker on the internet to become root or someone who has direct access to computer?

Comment: @MinimusHeximus yes, both of the above. Also, any kind of buggy program you run will now have access to the system and can destroy it, any mistake you make can now destroy the system etc.

Comment: @terdon: a reason I'm using a linux OS is to be less careful about security, I'm thinking someone with a direct access to the PC can boot in with an Ubuntu Live CD and do anything in less than 15 minutes, and what can be interesting for a hacker from internet about a personal computers' system files assuming they can access personal files without a password?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I login as root?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91598/how-do-i-login-as-root)

Comment: @MinimusHeximus if an attacker has physical access to a machine, then that machine is compromised, that is a given. If, however, you run everything as root, an attacker doesn't need physical access. If they break in, everything is wide open to them. Anyway, as I said, there are other dangers. For example, you can mistype something like `rm /bin` and that will break your system. All sorts of commands will be executable that can break your system. Also, any bug or malicious software you encounter can now break your system.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus as for why a hacker cares, two very simple reasons: 1) your bank details 2) using your computer as a platform or a stepping stone during an attack, making it part of a bot net etc etc. Seriously, this is a VERY bad idea.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am really against root being used as a default login.  This is a **really really really BAD** idea.

However, in cases where I'm working on something that requires a root terminal session with lots of `sudo` commands again and again it can get tiring to type `sudo`.

You can create a root session using the `sudo -i` command and enter your password once. When you are finished with whatever operations require root you can then exit and get back to a user level account.

```
mcgarrah@localhost:~$ sudo -i
root@localhost:~# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
root@localhost:~#
```

Again, running as root at all times is a **really bad idea**. Root allows for more access than a standard user needs and many of the features that make Linux more secure are no longer working for you. One example is running a web browser as root is insane.

Comment: thank you..i am not gonna do this..i just want to know :D

Comment: your answer is perfect...thats what i was looking for

Answer (score 4):

Type:

```
sudo visudo
```

Go to the end of the file and type:

```
<username> ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit, and press <kbd>Y</kbd> to save the changes.

Now open **System Settings->Keyboard** in that go to the Shortcut tab.

Launch terminal, press <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Backspace</kbd>; it will disable it.

Now go to Custom Shortcuts and click the plus (+) button at the bottom.

Give the name as **terminal** and the command as `sudo gnome-terminal`, then click Apply.

Then just go to some other location and come back to Custom Shortcuts.

Click terminal, press <kbd>Space</kbd> and now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Close the window.

That's it!

Now whenever you open the terminal through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, it will open as root.

Enjoy!