# Question about root user

Tags: 20.04, permissions, sudo, root

I've heard many times this phrase:

> Do not run application as **root**.

My question is, does any other user like Administrator which can perform administrative tasks using sudo count as **root**?

Comment: does [this](https://bencane.com/2012/02/20/why-you-should-avoid-running-applications-as-root/) help explain?

Comment: Also answered thoroughly at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

Comment: Already read both article and it's not answering my question. First article only talked about don't run on root which is not answering my question and the second one talked about root and sudo which both doesn't answering does administrator also categories as root or not. I question this as part of security reason and about user management on ubuntu since we have root user and administrator user that almost have the same power like root user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "root" and how can I become it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/608495/what-is-root-and-how-can-i-become-it)

Answer (score 1):

A root privileged account in a Unix/Linux system is an account with read/write access in all parts of the system, able to modify essential system files, install or remove global applications etc.

When you are using the sudo command, you are assuming root privileges for the action that follows sudo. For example

> sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

will enable your user account to assume root access necessary to update and upgrade components of your system. The && between the two actions means execute the second if the first has been successfully executed.

In conclusion, it's best to sudo only when necessary, to avoid possible system damage, especially if you are an inexperienced Linux user.

Everything can be repaired though :)

I hope I've helped you answer some questions.

Comment: Appreciate your answer, already understand about root and sudo in general. My question is more likely to be user management security rather than root or sudo itself. Just like my question above, for security reason does administrator who has the same power through sudo can have the same security risk as root user if running an application on itself?

Comment: yes, it does. same as logged in as root.