# Unable to install Matlab R2015a on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, matlab

I first mounted the iso file, and then after changing the directory to the virtual drive, and running the command `sudo ./install`, nothing happens. I don't get what I might be missing.

Comment: Is the file executable? do `sudo chmod +x file_name` first to make the file executable

Comment: I think so. since after listing the files in the virtual drive ($ ls), the install file name is green.

Comment: check the permissions associated with the file. That, IMO, is the more reliable way.

Comment: I'm new to Ubuntu. How can I check that? Many thanks

Comment: I tried ($ sudo chmod +x ./install) and also (($ sudo chmod - R +x ./install)) I got the result "chmod: cannot access './install': Permission denied)

Comment: For getting file permissions, use `stat -c "%a %n" file_name` and which command gives you permission denied?

Comment: both commands give me the permission denied message. I tried the `stat -c  "%a %n" install`. it gave me the message "555 install"

Comment: Do `ls -l file_name` and post the content here please.

Comment: the content is _-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 10483 Jan  3  2015 install_ FYI, install is the file name

Comment: That settles it. I have added an answer. Hope that works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comments, the file is owned by `root` user and `root` group. So you need to login as `root` by doing `su root` and then run the file using `./install`. If you face issues in logging as root, you can refer [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91598/how-do-i-login-as-root/). Let me know if it solves the problem for you. :)

Comment: it still has not worked. I should mention that I extracted .iso file and tried to run the install file from the extracted folder. I did `ls -l install` in the new folder and the content is _-rwxrwxrwx 1 essi essi 10483 Jan 3 2015 install_. I tried everything by login as a root since the beginning of the command line is `root@essi`.

Comment: @EssiA. Its getting confusing. What happens when you do `su root` and `./install` in the original setting that you described in your question?

Comment: After doing `./install` (as a `root` user), it does not give me any message and nothing happens (the pointer goes to the next line in the terminal as usual).

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l` after doing `chmod +x file_name` in the original setting?

Comment: _-rwxrwxrwx 1 essi essi 10483 Jan 3 2015 install_

Comment: And doing  a `sudo ./install` does not give any output?

Comment: no. It does not give me anything.