# Sudo not avaliable, cannot sudo su and root is not enabled

Tags: sudo, chown, pkexec

So im stuck in a loop after do something stupid

i had a / in a sudo chown command due to my fat fingers, i CTRL-X the operation but not before /etc was changed to a non root user.

so now trying to run sudo i get the following

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 1000, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialise policy plugin
```

trying to run the command

```
pkexec chown root:root -R /etc
```

doesnt work as this happens

```
ozhound@UbuntuServer:/$ pkexec chown root:root -R /etc
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.policykit.exec ===
Authentication is needed to run `/bin/chown' as the super user
Authenticating as: ozhound,,, (ozhound)
Password: 
polkit-agent-helper-1: error response to PolicyKit daemon:
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized

This incident has been reported.
```

I cannot login as root as i never enabled root

any suggestions? the other threads similar to this assume i have sudo access or the pkexec works.

ubuntu server 16.10

Comment: I suggest that you create a CD/DVD/USB boot drive from a small desktop iso file, for example **Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS or 16.10 desktop** or some linux rescue system. Boot your computer from that drive, mount the internal drive to `/mnt` and change the owner of `/mnt/etc` to 'root` alias user #0.

Answer (score 1):

I used the latest Ultimate Boot disk (which runs Redhat), mounted the drive and as sudodus suggested, I chowned the affected directories back to root:root. restarted and now sudo is available to me again.

Comment: Congratulations, and thanks for sharing your solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try these codes too:

`ls /dev/disk/by-uuid -alh`

Try to mount with the following codes:

`mount /dev/disk/sda1 /target`

`mount -t ext3 /dev/disk/sda1 /target`

`nano /etc/group`

Don´t forget your username must be added to admin.

I recommend this link: [How do I login as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91598/how-do-i-login-as-root)