# How do I become root when "su -i" is not supported?

Tags: command-line, sudo, 17.04, root, su

As far as I know the following command is supposed to make me root:

```
su -i
```

Nevertheless, when I type it in Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty Zapus, I get the following message:

```
su: invalid option -- 'i'
Usage: su [options] [LOGIN]
Options:
  -c, --command COMMAND         pass COMMAND to the invoked shell
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -, -l, --login                make the shell a login shell
  -m, -p,
  --preserve-environment        do not reset environment variables, and
                                keep the same shell
  -s, --shell SHELL             use SHELL instead of the default in passwd
```

I remember it was working some time ago. How do I re-enable it?

Answer (score 2):

> I remember it was working some time ago. How do I re-enable it?

**You were almost certainly using `sudo -i` before**, since [`su`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/su.1.html) doesn't support an `-i` option, and it has not supported such an option even in earlier releases. (Just to be sure, I've double-checked this on 16.04 LTS.) You can still use `sudo -i`.

On a system where root logins are enabled, you can enter `su` and authenticate with root's password. This gives you a root shell but it does not simulate a login shell. **It is similar to `sudo -s`** (or `sudo --shell`), which works even when the root account is disabled. With `sudo`, you  use your own  password. In the default configuration, you must be an administrator--i.e., a member of  the `sudo` group--to use it.

Similarly, if you can log in as root then you can also simulate a root login with `su -` (or `su -l`, or `su --login`). Passing the `-` flag to `su` sets environment variables similar to those that would be set in root's login environment and starts a login shell. **It is similar to `sudo -i`** (or `sudo --login`).

The most common way to use `sudo` is to run just a single command, just by running `sudo command args...`. This can also be done with `su` by passing the `-c`  flag, but it is awkward because the whole command including its arguments have to be [quoted](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) so it is passed as a single command-line argument to `su`: `su -c 'command args...'` (If you're not passing any arguments to the command, and the command name itself doesn't require quoting, then the quotes may be omitted.)

I mention all this *not* to provide a complete guide to `sudo`, and I recommend [`man sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/sudo.8.html), [RootSudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo), [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1388843), [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91598/how-do-i-login-as-root), the [tag wiki](https://askubuntu.com/tags/sudo/info), and the [upstream site](https://www.sudo.ws/) for more information. Aside from showing the commands you are most likely to want, my main point is that **even to do similar things, `sudo` and `su` use quite differently named short-form options**, including for `--login`. If you ever ran a command to get a root shell, and you passed `-i`, that command was most likely `sudo`.