# How to get superuser and install programs

Tags: 16.04, command-line

New Ubuntu 16.04.3 user. I know basic stuff and "study" all the time. Only me using this pc and desktop as user. I've tried to download React+associated programs like java etc. I do get at some point, but eventually something goes wrong because i'm not "allowed" to run programs in Terminal.

So, I've tried using

```
sudo
```

to run everything but it eventually crashes and errors at some point. 
And all of the other ways I could find on the internet. With

```
root -i
```

account I manage to download everything without errors, but then I can't find my downloads in the files.

When I try to get superuser acc. with info found on the internet using:

```
su - username
```

which should update my account to superuser `#` I still get `~$`
Is it possible that I've messed something up from the start? I installed Ubuntu with USB flash drive as main desktop and didn't have any problems.

Comment: "it eventually crashes and errors at some point" -- show us the error messages.

Comment: Hello! Please tell us what you actually want to do. I think you are trying to install an application. We can probably help you with that, but right now your question is quite confusing.

Comment: If you want to install, first of all have a look at the Ubuntu Software Centre.
Secondly, most "Ubuntu compatible" software often is with a .deb file [on the softwares' download page] which will [usually] allow you you to use the Software Centre to install.
As said above, what do you want to install ?

Answer (score 4):

My shot in the dark is based on this sentence: *So, I've tried using `sudo` **to run everything** but it eventually crashes and errors at some point.*

If you really do **run everything** by `sudo` probably the ownership to some files and folder in your user's home directory is changed to `root:root`, that causes a lot of errors. To check this, execute the following command and read the third and the fourth column (press `q` to exit):

```
ls -laR ~ | less
```

To recover from this situation execute:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:USER $HOME
```

This command will **ch**ange recursively the **own**ership of `/home/<user>` to your `user` and `:group`.

---

The command [`sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/sudo.8.html) allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser (*root*). So you should be really careful when you using this command. The rule number one [[read here]](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17137/editor-wars-aside-can-we-use-sudo-nano-when-talking-to-non-experts/17138#comment35266_17138): *don't use `sudo` with any graphical applications*. It probably will cause the situation described above. If you have done this, maybe your downloaded files are located in `/root/Downloads`.

By the login option `sudo -i` you will be able to become *root* via your own credentials - *username* and *password* - if you are a permitted user. But to [become *root*](https://askubuntu.com/a/91611/566421) by the command [`su`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/su.1.html) (**s**witch **u**ser as I call it :) the *root*'s account must be [enabled](https://askubuntu.com/q/44418/566421), that is not recommended.

---

To install software packages on first place (as @Piloti [suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978906/how-to-get-superuser-and-install-programs/978911#comment1572352_978906)) use [Ubuntu Software Center](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuSoftwareCenter), find [the application](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/) and click on the Install button. It will ask you for your password and if you are a permitted user, able to execute commands as *root*, the package will be installed.

If you already have downloaded any `.deb` package you could install it by double click on it and open with Ubuntu Software Center. You could install a `.deb` package also via the command line by the command [`dpkg -i`](https://askubuntu.com/a/40781/566421). You should execute this command as *root*:

```
sudo dpkg -i <package name>.deb
```

You could install software packages via the command line directly from Ubuntu repositories by the command [**`apt`**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/apt.8.html), that should be executed as *root* too. For example if you want to install Chromium browser execute the following command:

```
$ sudo apt install chromium-browser
[sudo] password for <user-name>: type your user's password here
```