# How do I access my files while I have trouble logging in with my account via GUI?

Tags: partitioning, login

I am actually using Ubuntu 14.04LTS. I kept the larger files in a .(dot)folder in administrator directory and my total disk space is filled.

I previously got the information that I have low disk space. Even though the desktop is blank and each and every time when I login in administrator it will give blank desktop it doesn't show any folder or applications.

But I can easily login into guest session, so how can I delete those administrator files to make free space by using guest session or some thing else?

Comment: No, you can't delete anything belonging to other users from a guest account.

Comment: I don't understand, do you mean `/home/root` directory? Why does somebody keeps there anything at all, and in so big amounts? This is odd.

Comment: yes sir (/home/root)sir actually  i kept the all video files (study lectures) and used the total memory of that administrator.now i want to make free space  because when i am going to login that administrator it will shows only desktop picture but not showing any files and applications also on the desktop.actually i tried to access the files from guest account but the /home/root files are not access  then how should i make free space and how should i open/view my administrative  files

Comment: Okay, I don't quite understand why when you login as root, it shows a blank desktop, but you can run a terminal, then use `cd /path/to/you/dir` to enter the directory with files, then check if you see them with the command `ls`. To remove files use `rm`. See also [why it is bad to login as root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-log-in-as-root). And no, you can't remove files belonging to root through a usual user — what would be the point of having an account with lower privileges if you could?

Comment: If you have physical access to the system you can do whatever you desire by booting from live media.

Answer (score 2):

If the free space is the problem, you can pres <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to open [tty1](https://askubuntu.com/a/481915/566421). Then log-in with the administrator's account and remove the unnecessary files by the command line. In the article [Guide to Unix/Commands/File System Utilities](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Guide_to_Unix/Commands/File_System_Utilities) are listed the basics about the commands `cd`, `ls`, `rm`, `rmdir`, etc.

Alternatively you could try to install [Midnight Commander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_Commander) (I hope there is a little free space left) that will display the file system in a more familiar way:

```
sudo apt install mc
```

Then run it by the command **`mc`**. The key <kbd>F8</kbd> is the Delete key, but be careful! <kbd>F5</kbd> is for Copy. Use <kbd>Tab ↹</kbd> to switch between the left and the right side. <kbd>F10</kbd> is for Quit. For more commands see the bottom line of the image below or press <kbd>F1</kbd> for Help.

[image]

> **Please read also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/978911/566421). There are provided few useful hints for beginners. I think you are just experiencing the problem with the wrong ownership described there.**

Answer (score 1):

You don't see your .folder on the desktop because files whose name begins with a '.' are hidden.
Login to the user who owns .folder, open a terminal and there do a `ls ~/Desktop/.folder` to see it and clean it up.

Comment: in administrator account just i can capable to login but after that not only .files but also any other file it doesn't visible and no application is also opened(file manager)

Comment: What exactly did you do to create this .folder?
Did you use sudo to get privileged and created /home/root/Desktop/.folder?

Comment: Sir I delete the files by taking command me now how should I leave this mc

Comment: So you have followed pa4080's suggestion and used mc. I see on the last line of his screenshot "10Quit" so the F10-key should make you leave mc.

Comment: Thank you so much  sir now I can access the administrator  account files and I have my important  files with me because  of you sir