# How can I verify my root password, when I know it but I need to check it?

Tags: command-line, server, password

I know my password on my server, but is there a command to check the password?

I can't use ssh because my ssh key is already copied, so is not useful.

I need something to ask me for the root password, and then tell me if it's wrong or not.

The question is not about checking whether a password is valid or right, but if the password is the real password, because when you login with ssh keys, you don't really use the password.

Comment: See [How do I login as root?](https://askubuntu.com/q/91598/295286) If you have a root password set, then you should be able to log in.  That's the simplest test

Comment: but I use digitalocean, and there is only a user: root, so i can't test it, but maybe creating a new user i guess.. to try login like root...

Comment: it's not duplicate, the question is not about check a password if is valid or right , but if the password is the real password, because when you login with ssh keys, you don't use really the password