# Can't login to root account, even with the correct password

Tags: login, password, root

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04. I'am trying to login to the root account.

I have created a root password with `sudo passwd root`, and I'm trying to login as root on the login page.

But even after entering the correct password multiple times it says that the authentication didn't work.

I tried running `sudo usermod -U root` to unlock the root account, but still a fail.

What else can I try doing?

Comment: @Artur Meinild I specifically changed the root password with `sudo passwd root`, and on the login page I entered the exact same password. What else am I supposed to do?

Comment: Sorry, I can't really help you there, since creating a root password is highly discouraged.

Comment: Are you trying to login as root in the terminal or GUI?

Comment: Why do you need a root account? Just use `sudo -i` to get to a root prompt if you need to do maintaince. A lot safer than using root. Regarding the command:  `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and `etc/pam.d/gdm-password` will need to be edited too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I login as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91598/how-do-i-login-as-root)

Answer (score 0):

Sudo -i will make one the root in Terminal. I use it for simple removals with cd and rm (-f).

But as the softwares can install up to everything as root w/o asking, one may need to do more add, remove, edit.