# Completely eliminating all password prompt 

Tags: security, password, prompt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable all password prompts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58372/how-to-disable-all-password-prompts)

I've looked all over Google for a way to disable those annoying password prompts. So far the only one that's worked is editing the `sudoer` file, but then this only  disables the Password prompt for sudo in the terminal program. I still need to trash the one for su and the one for installing software.

Another irritant is that this OS won't allow you to put a simple password , it has to be *unmemorizable*.

I'd much prefer the possibility of some intruder trashing my setup than having that annoying Password prompt constantly pop up - so much so that I resorted to putting a text file on my desktop with the passwords on it, so I can easily retrieve them.

Comment: Did you take a look at [How to disable all password prompts?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/58372/how-to-disable-all-password-prompts)

Comment: Please take a look at http://askubuntu.com/a/16179/6807 before you do so.

Answer (score 0):

On `12.04` for package management

```
gksudo gedit  /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/package-manager.pkla
```

Use this, save

```
[Install package file]
Identity=unix-group:sudo
Action=org.debian.apt.install-file;org.debian.apt.update-cache;org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages;org.debian.apt.upgrade-packages
ResultActive=yes

[Install package synaptic]
Identity=unix-group:sudo
Action=com.ubuntu.pkexec.synaptic
ResultActive=yes

[Change add repo]
Identity=unix-group:sudo
Action=com.ubuntu.softwareproperties.applychanges;org.debian.apt.change-repository
ResultActive=yes
```

As far as a password - when you first install Ubuntu still allows a min. password of 1 character. After install it goes up to 6 min.