# Is it possible to open directories as administrator?

Tags: nautilus, root

I want to have a root privileges on some directories. How can I do this?

Comment: In nautilus or some other file manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in many ways:

- [Log in as root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44418/how-to-enable-root-login)
- Open nautilus as a root

  ```
  gksu nautilus
  ```
- You can add "Open as administrator" as an extension to your right click:

  1. Download the nautilus-gksu package for your architecture from either of these 2 locations, and save it in your downloads folder.

     **32 bit**: [Direct link from ubuntu.mirror.cambrium.nl](http://ubuntu.mirror.cambrium.nl/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gksu/nautilus-gksu_2.0.2-5ubuntu2_i386.deb)

     **64 bit**: [Direct link from ubuntu.mirror.cambrium.nl](http://ubuntu.mirror.cambrium.nl/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gksu/nautilus-gksu_2.0.2-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb)
  2. On your 64 bit install downloaded nautilus-gksu_2.0.2-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb & extracted right in your Downloads folder

     ```
     sudo cp ~/Downloads/nautilus-gksu_2.0.2-5ubuntu2_amd64/usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-2.0/libnautilus-gksu.so /usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0
     ```
  3. On your 32 bit install downloaded nautilus-gksu_2.0.2-5ubuntu2_i386.deb & again extracted in Downloads folder so terminal command

     ```
     sudo cp ~/Downloads/nautilus-gksu_2.0.2-5ubuntu2_i386/usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-2.0/libnautilus-gksu.so /usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0
     ```

Answer (score 12):

Create a simple nautilus script can also open a folder as root.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
gksudo nautilus $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS
```

Save the above script as `Open folder as root` in your `~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/`. On right click you will have an option under scripts, Open folder as root. And you can open a folder as root after providing your root password.

Do not forget to give the script execution permission. You can use in terminal,

```
chmod +x ~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/Open\ folder\ as\ root
```

Or you can right click on the file, then go to **Properties** >> **Permissions** and check the box corresponds to **Execute** to give the script execution permission.

[image]

[image]

To use `gksudo` you need to install `gksu`. In Ubuntu 13.04 onwards it is not install by default. You can install it using,

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

---

**Open files and folders as root**

There is a nice application `xdg-open` which can open any arbitrary file or URL in the user's preferred application. One can replace `nautilus` with `xdg-open` in the above script and it will enable one to open folders as well as all files as root.<sup>[Proposed by [Sadi](https://askubuntu.com/users/47343/sadi)]</sup> It increases the applicability of the code. The modified script will look like,

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# script_name: open as root
gksudo xdg-open $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS
```

Comment: I think you can make this **Nautilus Script** applicable to files as well by replacing `nautilus` with `xdg-open`

Comment: @Sadi very good proposal indeed, I will edit it. now i am on mobile.

Comment: easy & nice script souravc, just note you have to change file properties to allow execution (for those who do not know it).

Comment: @bob thanks for pointing it out. I should mention it explicitly.

Answer (score 9):

My solution is to add an option for “Open as Administrator” to directories.

As you can see, there is no “Open as Administrator” option when you right click on a folder:

[image: Screenshot of right-click menu]

First, add the package repository by opening your Terminal and typing:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
```

A message will appear:

```
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 This PPA Contains Applications for Ubuntu/Linux Mint from different sources but debianized by http://www.NoobsLab.com
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/apps
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it
```

Press Enter.

Now we’ve added the repository, it’s time to update our sources:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

After you update, it’s time to install the package we want for our issue:

```
$ sudo apt-get install open-as-administrator
```

Finally, you should restart Nautilus:

```
$ nautilus -q
```

And now the “Open as Administrator” option should appear:

[image: Screenshot of right-click menu]

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo -H nautilus /path/to/folder/
```