# how to make shortcut with command?

Tags: shortcuts

I want to open a `.jar` file with java. It is located in `/home/myusername`. I had to type in the terminal to open it

```
java -jar filename.jar
```

I want to have a shortcut that if I click it, it will run the command and launch the program with java automatically..

is there anything I could do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create an Empty Document and name it `yourchoosenname.sh`

(**.sh** means that this file contain commands to run )

[image]

Second open this file and add the code you write in Terminal, adjusting the path as appropriate:

```
java -jar /home/$USER/filename.jar
```

Third make this file executable:

Right click on the file, then to the Permissions tab.

[image]

Fourth run this file by double clicking.

Comment: Please don't post commands as images, it means we have to copy your suggestion by hand in order to try it. That's what code blocks are for.

Comment: why your are trying to down vote all my answers !! what should you copy here ? and you dont have the right to tell me what to do

Comment: images are allowed and people should learn how to write commands , not only copy paste

Comment: I did not _tell_ you what to do, I _asked_ you to please not post images of commands. I also (in my [other](http://askubuntu.com/questions/195420/how-to-open-directories-as-administrator/410929#comment563468_410929) comment pointed you to the [meta question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695) where this was discussed. But you're quite right, the images you posted here are fine. I was looking for posts that had commands as images to edit them but I read too quickly and thought this one needed it as well. My apologies.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `.desktop` file on your desktop using your favourite text editor  and save the following code in a it.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=myjavafile
Type=Application
Exec=java -jar /home/myusername/filename.jar
Icon=/path/to/java.jpg
```

You need to change `Name` and jar file name in `Exec` field. If you want to set an icon for it put a 128x128 `.jpg` or `.png` image for java and specify it accordingly on `Icon` field. Otherwise remove the last line.

[image]

Give it execution permission,

```
chmod +x /home/myusername/Desktop/<filename>.desktop
```

Now you can click on it to open your `jar` file using java directly.