# How to find reasons for journal recovery

Tags: 12.10, data-recovery, ext3

Recently, when I've been starting my computer I'm informed that it is recovering the journal for one of my ext3 partitions.

One might expect this behaviour if the computer shutdown improperly, but, as far as I can tell this is occurring after normal shutdowns.

Additionally, the number of inodes which are found to be orphaned and cleared is only one or two in these cases.

I have performed an fsck, but the situation continues.

Which logs files can I check to try to find out why this is happening? What are some reasons it may have happened? How can I resolve it?

**UPDATE**

fstab is as follows:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=ead12a48-4a3b-4e3a-b611-d3fc62e8716a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,noatime,nodiratime 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=217f1c44-5d04-4c75-9d4a-2a70b1726434 /home           ext3    defaults,noatime,nodiratime        0       2
```

**UPDATE 2**

`cat /var/log/fsck/{checkfs,checkroot}` returns `(Nothing has been logged yet.)` twice.

Comment: @Rinzwind, `filesystem state: clean`.

Comment: I am out of suggestions @richard :) Here have a bounty on your question >:)

Comment: @Rinzwind, let me check the filesystem state another time or two just to be sure that the shutdown was symptomatic.

Comment: Do the files `/var/log/fsck/{checkfs,checkroot}` something? What is your system date and what time shows your BIOS?

Comment: @qbi, those files both show `(Nothing has been logged yet.)` I'll check the BIOS time shortly.

Comment: What kind of hardware do you have? Type of SSD, storage controller, etc. I've seen OCZ SSDs claiming a write had performed, but it was actually only written to its DRAM cache. Whenever my laptop powered off or suspended the DRAM cache buffer wasn't fully flushed yet and my `/home` got corrupted more and more silently... By the time I found the cause and a workaround in the shutdown scripts (extra sleep) it died completely. I changed it to an Intel SSD and *boom* all problems vanished.

Comment: @gertvdijk, I have an HDD. How would I check the cache settings?

Comment: @Richard The cache I was talking about is properly handled by the kernel by doing a `sync` on unmount. The issue I was talking about was a plain hardware problem. I haven't seen HDDs doing this, so I think this is not applicable to you. Please do include all the details I asked for. And please *integrate* the information in your question, rather than posting *update 2*. We can see the differences if you update your question.

Comment: @richard which of the 2 is the best answer? >:)

Answer (score 2):

Your only ext3 partition happens to be `/home`. One possible reason for your problem is that `/home` isn't being unmounted because it is in use at the time your system is being shut down. Since `/home` shouldn't be in use when no normal user is logged in, identifying if it is in use when nobody is logged in is one way of identifying if this particular possible issue is the cause of your specific problem.

1. Temporarily [enable root login](https://askubuntu.com/a/44419/7808) on your system (we'll disable it again later). This will allow you to log in without accessing `/home`, so that you can check whether anything else is using it and whether it unmounts correctly.
2. Log out.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to a text virtual terminal.
4. Log in as root. This will start a shell in root's home directory (`/root`) which is outside of `/home`.
5. Try to unmount `/home` by typing `umount /home` (no sudo is required since you're already root).
6. If this succeeds, then this isn't your problem. If it fails, then this is your problem. If the reason is that the filesystem is in use, then the command `fuser -m /home` will list processes using `/home` which you can investigate.
7. Mount `/home` again by typing `mount /home`.
8. Log out with the command `exit`.
9. Switch back to the graphical login screen by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.
10. Log back in as yourself.
11. [Disable root login](https://askubuntu.com/a/44419/7808) to return your system to its original configuration.

This may or may not identify the cause of your specific problem, but should work to identify processes that are preventing `/home` from being cleanly unmounted on system shutdown in the general case.

Comment: I gave this a try and, indeed, it would not unmount. Using `fuser -vm /home` showed that there was single process with PID `kernel` accessing the file-system. I'm not sure where to go from here. Is it possible to see what file is being accessed? I have an inkling that it may be related to the home directory being encrypted (ecryptfs).

Comment: Could you paste the output of `fuser` into your question?

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned in your comment eCryptfs is a possible cause for your problem. To check this out do the following steps:

1. Log out and log in as a different user
2. Try to open your files in `/home/richard` (or however your user is called).
3. If you can access and read the files, your home was not correct unmounted.

Another thing you can do as user is to enter `ecryptfs-umount-private`. This scripts quits on success with the message:

> Your private directory has been unmounted.

On error you might get the message:

> ```
> fopen: No such file or directory
> Cannot chdir into mountpoint.
> ```

In the latter case the problem are often missing symlinks. So do the following steps:

1. Login as your normal user
2. Make sure your home directory is *not* encrypted (You can read all files).
3. Open a terminal (If you are working in a terminal, just type `cd` to get into your `$HOME`).
4. Type `ln -s /home/.ecryptfs/YOUR_USERNAME/.ecryptfs` and `ln -s /home/.ecryptfs/YOUR_USERNAME/.Private`.

The main point are the symbolic links in the last step. In some cases they are missing. This leads to not encrypting and umounting your data in the home.

However if the problem persists then there might also the file `$HOME/.ecryptfs/auto-umount` missing. If this is the case your home directory will not be automatically unmounted. Just enter `touch $HOME/.ecryptfs/auto-umount` to change it.

Comment: I tried this and could not access the files, so I guess the logout went correctly. Is there any log file for checking to see if this happens consistently?